# Postgres Full Text Search Jsonb Array column does not show first row

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, jsonb

Pgsql is unable to perform indexed full text search onto jsonb column containing an array when looking for the first row in the table.

Table is nothing more than just `Id` and `Foo` which is `jsonb` column.

The case is that I have an empty database with predefined gin index `repro_fts_idx` on `make_tsvector` function. `make_tsvector` creates `tsvector` from given `jsonb` column.

When I add a new item into the table, I expect it to appear in `make_tsvector` function in a form of `tsvector`. It's there.
Also, I expect that if I run full text search query onto it, it would appear in search results. However, this is not the case because it returns empty specifically for the first row. It simply does not take it into account.
If I add one more row which is completely the same, the system is able to find it with the same query.

here is a small repro case:

```
-- drop table cp."Repro" cascade

CREATE TABLE cp."Repro" (
    "Id" serial NOT NULL,
    "Foo" jsonb NULL
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cp.make_tsvector(in_t cp."Repro")
 RETURNS tsvector
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 IMMUTABLE
AS $function$ begin    
                        return to_tsvector(jsonb_agg(x.prop))
                        from (SELECT CONCAT( jsonb_array_elements(in_t."Foo") ->> 'Name', ' ', jsonb_array_elements(in_t."Foo") ->> 'Address' ) as prop from cp."Repro" f) as x;
                        END;
                        $function$
;


CREATE INDEX repro_fts_idx ON cp."Repro" USING gin (cp.make_tsvector(cp."Repro".*)) WITH (fastupdate=off, gin_pending_list_limit='64');


INSERT INTO cp."Repro"
("Foo")
VALUES('[{"Name": "Sup", "Address": "Adress", "IsCurrent": true}]');

-- just in case it's the indexing issue
-- REINDEX INDEX cp.repro_fts_idx;

select * from cp."Repro"

select cp.make_tsvector(x) from cp."Repro" x

select * from ts_stat('select cp.make_tsvector(x) from cp."Repro" x')

-- explain analyze
SELECT *
 FROM "cp"."Repro" x where cp.make_tsvector(x) @@ 'sup:*'::tsquery


 INSERT INTO cp."Repro"
("Foo")
VALUES('[{"Name": "Sup", "Address": "Adress", "IsCurrent": true}]');


-- explain analyze
SELECT *
 FROM "cp"."Repro" x where cp.make_tsvector(x) @@ 'sup:*'::tsquery
```

**UPD: THE ANSWER**

The function was wrong since it referenced both input row and whole table.
The correct function is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cp.make_tsvector(in_t cp."Repro")
 RETURNS tsvector
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 IMMUTABLE
AS $function$
                    BEGIN
                        return string_agg(lower(regexp_replace(coalesce(x::text, ''), '[|&\\*:()'']+', ' ', 'g')), ' ')::tsvector FROM (SELECT CONCAT( jsonb_array_elements(in_t."Foo") ->> 'Name', ' ', jsonb_array_elements(in_t."Foo") ->> 'Address' ) AS x) AS x;
                    END;
                $function$
;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely your function is wrong.  It shouldn't be referring both to its input record, `in_t`, and to the whole underlying table, `cp."Repro"`.  (And since it is referring to `cp."Repro"`, then it isn't really immutable.  Bad things happen when you lie to the system about the immutability of your function.)

Since the table is empty at the time the first row is inserted, selecting from the empty table inside the function doesn't give any results, yielding a NULL result to be indexed.  This can be seen with:

```
truncate cp."Repro" ;
select cp.make_tsvector(row(1,'[{"Name": "Sup", "Address": "Adress", "IsCurrent": true}]'));
 make_tsvector 
---------------
 (null)
```

Even if your make_tsvector wasn't broken, it still seems to be useless.  It is basically just a broken re-implementation of to_tsvector.  What is it supposed to accomplish?

Comment: Basically you are right, the function was wrong in the place you pointed to. 
Updated the question with the response.